# Starting tty.js on Boot

Tags: linux, bash, node.js, tty

I'm trying to start a tty.js shell on boot which is pretty easy with a cron job on boot, but it doesn't start the environment correctly.  It doesn't have the right $PATH and such.  It is not executing the right scripts like /etc/environment, ~/.bashrc, etc.  Is there a way to start tty.js on boot with the same environment when you login.

Answer (score 1):

On Gentoo at least, you set up the environment explicitly using the **source /etc/profile** command. It resets environment variables and the likes. Give that a try.

Comment: This only works partially.  It still doesn't parse and set /etc/environment.  However, it led me to correct way to do this.

Comment: Glad to be able to help, if you want, can you edit your answer to include how you did it in case someone else stumbles upon it who's lost also :)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu cron jobs at boot and upstart do not load /etc/environment because that is normally done by pam_env.so when you login.  However, **su** does the proper loading of /etc/environment and /etc/profile. So in a cron job at boot or in upstart you could do something like:

```
exec su username -c "/home/username/bin/tty.js 1> /home/username/tty.log 2> /home/username/tty.log &"
```